# javafx and css how to use variables

Tags: css, javafx, fxml

i have a login screen and when you dont fill in right username and pw the username and password text-field will flash red and then need to fade back to white over a certain time (1 or 2 seconds probably). The biggest problem however is that i dont know how to implement variables in the css. This is what i have to change the color

```
package com.cortex.gui;

import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.text.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.io.IOException;

public class FXMLController {
Stage stage;
Parent root;
double fade = 1;
Timeline borderFade = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(100), ae -> faultLine(fade)));
//login screen objects
@FXML    private Button loginButton;
@FXML    private TextField usernameField;
@FXML    private PasswordField passwordField;
//main screen objects
@FXML    private Button returnButton;

@FXML
protected void handleLoginButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException     {
    if (passwordField.getText().equals("password") && usernameField.getText().equals("username")) {
        if (event.getSource() == loginButton) {
            stage = (Stage) loginButton.getScene().getWindow();
            sceneSetter("/InterfaceMain.fxml");
        }
    }
    else {
        borderFade.setCycleCount(10);
        borderFade.play();
    }
}

protected void faultLine(double i){
    usernameField.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgb(220, 60, 20, fade)");
    passwordField.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(220, 60, 20, fade)")
    fade = fade - 0.1;
}
}
```

i want to use the fade variable for it but it gives a parsing error since java doesnt seem to recognise it as a double here.

Comment: What exactly is the error message and where does it occur and what exactly do you want to achieve with the css? Could you maybe simplify the example so that only the relevant parts for the error remain?

Comment: How exactly die you define your variable fade?

Answer (score 0):

setStyle's parameter is a String, so what you want is a String containing the value of your double "fade". Java does this automaticly when concatenating a double with a String.

```
protected void faultLine(double i){
    usernameField.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgb(220, 60, 20, " + fade + ")");
    passwordField.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(220, 60, 20, " + fade + ")");
    fade = fade - 0.1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the double to string and then concat it like

```
protected void faultLine(double i){
    usernameField.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgb(220, 60, 20," +String.valueOf(fade)+")");
    passwordField.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(220, 60, 20,"+String.valueOf(fade)+")");
    fade = fade - 0.1;
}
```

You can also use `Double.toString(fade);`

Comment: alright thanks guys, i did use the 1 + fade but then i forgot to do 1 + fade + My bad -.-